# Passing a string variable between two foreach-loops in one method

Tags: c#, foreach

This is my code:

```
public void refresh_SID(string callsign) {
    // zjistime si vsechny potrebne informace o danem letu
    XmlNodeList lety = airplanes.SelectNodes("/vEsup/flights/LKPR/odlety/let");
    XmlNodeList sids = airports.SelectNodes("/vEsup/config/airports/LKPR/sidstar/sids/sid");
    XmlNodeList getQfu = airplanes.SelectNodes("/vEsup/airports/airport/");
    MessageBox.Show(callsign);
    foreach (XmlNode let in lety) {
        if(let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("callsign").Value == callsign) {
            string adep = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("adep").Value;
            foreach(XmlNode letiste in getQfu) {
                if(adep == letiste.Attributes.GetNamedItem("icao").Value);
                string qfu = letiste.Attributes.GetNamedItem("rwy").Value;
            }
            string depRunway = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("deprwy").Value; 
            string type = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("type").Value;
            string exitpoint = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("exitpoint").Value;
            string rules = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("rules").Value;
            ComboBox sidRoute = new ComboBox();
            Load_SID(depRunway, qfu, type, exitpoint, rules, sids, sidRoute);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't merge the two `foreach` loops in one, because in the second, I need to use the `adep` string I get in the first one, and I need the second to be a separate `foreach` loop as it has to check different part of the XML file. So now, when calling the `Load_SID` method, the `qfu` doesn't exist. Any way to get it there?

Comment: This looks flawed - you extract multiple values for `qfu` from the XML but you perform only a single call to `Load_SID()` in each iteration of the outer loop. Which value do you want to use in this call? The first? The last? It does not matter, they are all the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get error doesn't exist because variable qfu is not in the scope when you invoke method Load_SID.

Try this:

```
    ...
    string adep = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("adep").Value;
    string qfu = string.Empty;
    foreach(XmlNode letiste in getQfu)
    {
       if(adep == letiste.Attributes.GetNamedItem("icao").Value);
            qfu = letiste.Attributes.GetNamedItem("rwy").Value;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Well, it seems to be working, when i click on qfu in the code, it also marks the declaration, so I guess it is correct, BUT another problem occured, when i try to debug this, I get an unhandled exception error and it marks the line `XmlNodeList getQfu = airplanes.SelectNodes("/vEsup/airports/airport/");` saying "Expression must evaluate to a node-set.". Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you indent the line `qfu = letiste....`? It wasn't in the original, and the assignment does **not** depend on the if (Notice the `;` at the end of the if). Or did I just spot a bug? ;)

Comment: Yeah there is semicolon, this indentation doesn't affect on behaviour so it's ok. Maybe it's bug:)

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring qfu for the duration of the inner foreach single iteration, and it's out of scope when youtry to call it. you need to declare it outside the inner foreach and when you have the appropriate value, exit the foreach and make your call.